# Copyright and transcripts

Tags: copyright

Am I breaking copyright law if I embed an educational video on my site and also provide a transcript of the video?

I have searched the w3c website as well as Youtube and cannot get a clear answer.

Comment: What is your jurisdiction? In this case, what country are you in?

Comment: "I have searched the w3c website as well as Youtube" - Neither of these is a good place for legal information or information about copyright.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the video is copyright and you are not the rights holder:

- embedding it is copyright violation unless you have permission (linking is OK). For example, YouTube allows this if it is done in accordance with their Terms of Service.
- making a transcript is copyright violation unless you have permission.

In either case, [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) or [fair dealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_dealing) defences might apply depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the specific video you want is, but if it is copyrighted and not your's you need to get permission to use it.